# Julia - ERROR: cannot assign variable ImageAxes.data from module Main

Tags: dataframe, julia

I wish to run the example from [here](https://github.com/JuliaStats/GLM.jl/blob/master/docs/src/examples.md), but I get this error:

```
julia> using DataFrames, GLM

julia> data = DataFrame(X=[1,2,3], Y=[2,4,7])
```

> ERROR: cannot assign variable ImageAxes.data from module Main
>   Stacktrace:  [1](https://github.com/JuliaStats/GLM.jl/blob/master/docs/src/examples.md) top-level scope at none:0

Can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ImageAxes.jl defines a deprecated function `data`. You must have used this function before trying to assign a value to `data` variable.

Now to understand what is going on consider the following example. I am using a fresh REPL session:

```
julia> sin = 1
1

julia> sin
1

julia> cos(1)
0.5403023058681398

julia> cos = 1
ERROR: cannot assign variable Base.cos from module Main

julia> log # it is enough to reference a function ho have this situation - you do not have to call it
log (generic function with 19 methods)

julia> log = 1
```

You can notice that you could bind a value to `sin` (although it is a standard function) to `1` BEFORE `sin` was referenced to (e.g. called) in the session. On the other hand we have called `cos` first before trying to assign a value to `cos` variable. This introduced `cos` into global scope, and as `cos` is a function rebinding the value assigned to `cos` is not allowed.